# Issue with JsonQueryElasticSearch processor generating flowfile

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-nifi

I was trying to implement the below in nifi

Use case : do a curl http request with search parameters for elasticSearch query and send response with result set via nifi.

Nifi Flow :

HandleHttpRequest --> EvaluateJsonPath (to get the required fields to pass them to ElasticSearch Query) --> JsonQueryElasticSearch --> Publish to Kafka -->  HandleHttpResponse

the JsonQueryElasticSearch works well giving me the correct result set.

Issue here is it generates an extra flow file from HandleHttpRequest processor along with the results set from elasticsearch. I am not sure how to ignore or delete or filter that flow file in order pass the data from JsonQueryElasticSearch to Publish Kafka processor or to HandleHttpResponse.

I wish i could share the flow xml file or the screenshot of the configuration unfortunately i cannot due to organization policies.

Please advise if there is any solution for this.
Thanks in Advance and appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mike Thomsen, any advise or suggestions here?

Comment: which processor generates extra flow file and can’t you filter that out via some specific attribute by using routeonattribute ?

Comment: JsonQueryElasticSearch is the one that generated 2 flow files one from the resultset and the other one from the HandleHttpRequest. let me see if i can use routeonAttribute if that helps

Comment: https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-elasticsearch-restapi-nar/1.12.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.elasticsearch.JsonQueryElasticsearch/  It has 4 out-going relationships - have you tried branching 'hits' or 'aggregations' (depending on your query)?

Comment: @Sdairs, yes seperating hits/aggregations and original to seperate processors works. initially i was routing hits/aggregations/original to one single processor. Thank you that was helpful